# What would be the right way to run python and bash commands in one cell in Jupyter on Mac?

Tags: bash, macos, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to set a voice notification in a Jupyter cell right after a python code by using a bash command:

```
#Some python code

%%bash 
say -v Daniel The programm execution has been finished
```

But that raises syntax error.

What would be the right way to solve it?